# Adding of Terminal Plugin in Kate

Tags: kate

[image]

I have installed kate in system, but terminal is showing blank, I have added plugin of terminal, but I still can't use the terminal.

Comment: make sure is installed konsole too. `sudo apt install konsole`

Comment: But is weird, if you installed kate by `sudo apt install kate`, konsole should have also been installed.

Comment: Yes, I have installed Konsole too, But it showing the same

Comment: Yes, I have installed Kate from Terminal

Comment: uninstall and reinstall kate

Comment: I didn't need to log out and back on Ubuntu 18.04. Which version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: I just tried with Kate/Konsole on Ubuntu 19.04. It works there as well. No need to log out and back. Can you try with a new user? Perhaps some config file has been messed up? Uninstalling and re-installing won't affect config files in you home folder. If it works with a new user, there could possibly be permission issues with some files in your home folder. Does `find . ! -user $USER -ls` return a lot of hits?

Comment: One more question: did you install kate/konsole with `--no-install-recommends`?

Comment: Here's what I see on 19.04: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLB3g.png